# Android getting GPS Location on a fixed interval, how much impact on Battery and what goes in the background If we are getting location per hour

Tags: android, gps, location, power-management

When getting GPS location on a fixed interval (say per hour), does this drain the battery every hour, every minute or only when either actually getting the location each hour or updating the location.  I'm eager to know what goes on in the background.

Here is what [this reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates%28long,%20float,%20android.location.Criteria,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) says

> **"Background services should be careful about setting a sufficiently high minTime so that the device doesn't consume too much power by keeping the GPS or wireless radios on all the time. In particular, values under 60000ms are not recommended. "**

So I'm hoping that when the location is changed, or after minTime, the GPS radios are on, and after getting location, the GPS radios are off

Can anyone confirm this to be true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates%28long,%20float,%20android.location.Criteria,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) we can decide that expensive battery using happens when GPS engine try to get new location and we can control freqency of this using method `public void requestLocationUpdates (long minTime, float minDistance, Criteria criteria, PendingIntent intent)`

Comment: Edited my question, please check

Comment: @g-b-1981 I just tested this behaviour. It seems it working as: 1. if we haven't location we will try found it (i'm not sure but i get on my device (G1, android 2.2) next behaviour: while not found location it try in some fixed time interval which length depends on minTime and go to sleep some other time interval) 2. if we have location we will search new one only after minTime or minDistance condition have been released Between searching location it use battery not so much P.S. sorry for my english and commenting here (i haven't permission commenting questions)

Comment: That means, between the two times (it searches for location) or after the location changed, the gps radio goes off, correct?  so not a bad effect on battery :)

Comment: @g-b-1981 yes. it almost not using battery

Answer (score 1):

Battery consumed is at its peak at the time when location manager tries to pinpoint your location(you can observe GPS icon blinking on status bar at that time) and this happens once in an hour in your case.. So GPS is automatically turned to "not available" state once you get a location until your next hour is reached..

And the line "In particular, values under 60000ms are not recommended" is said because it takes some time for GPS to point out your location, typically a minute maybe depending on your satellite strength.. So if your minTime is set to less than a minute(60000ms) its like your GPS is almost on for all the time..

[Read here for more details](http://blog.doityourselfandroid.com/2010/12/25/understanding-locationlistener-android/)